# Why does xcopy not copy files when using these parameters?

Tags: windows, cmd, xcopy

I have a simple xcopy script that I'm running from the command line that reads a CSV file of directories and file names.  I've used a very similar script with no problems before.  Here is the script:

```
Z:\HOME\>for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4" %i in (Z:\HOME\MissingImages.csv) do
echo f | xcopy "Y:\%j\%k\%l" "C:\Horizon\%j\%k\%l" >> Z:\HOME\MissingImagesLog.txt
```

However, it is not copying any of the files over
Here is an entry from the log file:

```
Does C:\Horizon\K\00\6bef500f.IMG  specify a file name
or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? f
0 File(s) copied
```

It's finding the images because if I change the root directory to something else the script will just populate the log file with `0 File(s) copied` for all entries, so the files are there and can be seen...

Also, the `Z:\` drive is on a network and not local, but again I have used a very similar script across a network without problems (it just takes longer).

I've tried different options like `/i`, `/s`, etc. but I can't seem to get it to copy any files over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's annoying;  I found the issue.  It looks like when I generated my CSV file, it put a space at the end of each line, so xcopy was looking for files that had a space after the extension.

The thing that was throwing me off was that it was finding the files, but couldn't copy them, making me think it was a network or xcopy issue.

I just ran a sed script to remove the eol spaces and the xcopy script is now working as expected.

Answer (score 11):

xcopy will also report `0 File(s) copied` if you use forward slashes "/" in paths instead of backslashes "\", though ONLY if you've enclosed the path in quotes.

1. This fails with "0 File(s) copied"

   ```
   xcopy "pathname1/file" pathname2\file
   ```
2. This fails with "Invalid number of parameters"

   ```
   xcopy pathname1/file pathname2\file
   ```
3. This works just fine

   ```
   xcopy pathname1\file pathname2\file
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It asks because it doesn't know whether you want to copy to directory (to be created) or you provide the full target pathname. 
This will ask:

```
xcopy pathname1\file.from pathname2\file.to
```

However, adding slash will tell that you copy to directory:

```
xcopy pathname1\file.from pathname2\to\
```

But I haven't found the way to tell explicitly that I want to copy and rename file, except

```
echo Y | xcopy pathname1\file.from pathname2\file.to
```

I played a bit with your case (with **for**, **do** and **xcopy**) and found out that even if it asks *Does SOMEFILE specify a file name or directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?* it is provided with **f** from **echo** and it's copied successfully. Thus, it's not a problem with file/directory specifying, but with copying through network itself.

Comment: isn't that the way it's supposed to be, though? Isn't the flow: 1.Xcopy command runs; 2.prompts for file or directory; 3.echo f is executed to complete xcopy command; 4.next xcopy command runs etc. Why would it be problematic for echo f to execute after xcopy?

Comment: Updated, it's ok with echo f. How is Z: mapped to system?

Comment: Found the issue; it was how the csv was created. Thanks for your help!